# Ruby & ActiveRecord: referring to integer fields by (uniquely mapped) strings

Tags: ruby, activerecord

While its not my application a simple way to explain my problem is to assume I'm running a URL shortener. Rather than attempt to try and figure out what the next string I should use as the unique section of the URL, I just index all my URLs by integer and map the numbers to strings behind the scenes, essentially just changing the base of the number to, let's say, 62: a-z + A-Z + 0-9.

In ActiveRecord I can easily alter the reader for the `url_id` field so that it returns my base 62 string instead of the number being stored in the database:

```
class Short < ActiveRecord::Base
  def url_id
    i = read_attribute(:convo)

    return '0' if i == 0
    s = ''
    while i > 0
      s << CHARS[i.modulo(62)]
      i /= 62
    end
    s
  end
end
```

*but* is there a way to tell ActiveRecord to accept `Short.find(:first,:conditions=>{:url_id=>'Ab7'})`, ie. putting the 'decoding' logic into my `Short` ActiveRecord class?

I guess I could define my own `def self.find_by_unique_string(string)`, but that feels like cheating somehow! Thanks!

Comment: A bit of poking around makes me think I'd need to use `before_find` - sound about right? Does this callback even exist??

Comment: Why does defining your own method feel like cheating? That's called programming. The kind of solution you seem to be looking for would likely require monkey-patching ActiveRecord, which should feel much more like cheating.

Comment: ActiveRecord is such a well thought out library I thought they'd have planned for this already :P Sounds like you've got the best idea tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is to actually add an extra field to your database table for `unique_string` and then use a `before_save` callback to put the encoded value in this field. Then, once the record is saved, you will be able to use that field in any kind of `find`.